# Test collection does not contain several members

Tags: c#, collections, nunit, assertion, nunit-3.0

Consider this code:

```
const string user8 = "user8";
const string user9 = "user9";
string[] users = { "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", user8 };
```

I want to test that the `users` does not contain either user8 or user9. I used to use

```
Assert.That(users, Is.Not.SupersetOf(new[] {user8, user9 }));
```

Unfortunately, it pass the test (which is not expected). I can use

```
Assert.That(users, Does.Not.Contains(user8).And.Not.Contains(user9));
```

But that will be problematic if I intend to test collection agains more than 2 members. Is there any better syntax? I'm using NUnit 3.4.

Note: the goal isn't just about the test outcome, but should be proper assertion so whenever test fail, we can determine faster from the error message. This is an error message example from last example (using `Does.Not.Contains`)

"Expected: not collection containing "user8" and not containing "user9"
But was:  < "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user8" >"

Comment: Have you tried `CollectionAssert`?

Comment: `Assert.That(new[] {user8Name, user9Name }, Is.Not.SubSetOf(users));`

Comment: @Hendry there are several methods in `CollectionAssert`. Can you go more specific? FYI, I prefer to use [constraint](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Constraints). But it it's the only solution, then it shouldn't be problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging about creating custom constraint and downloading NUnit source code, so I decide to create custom CollectionContainsConstraint a

```
/// <summary>
/// CollectionContainsAnyConstraint is used to test whether a collection
/// contains any member in expected collection.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class CollectionContainsAnyConstraint<T> : CollectionContainsConstraint
{
    public CollectionContainsAnyConstraint(IEnumerable<T> expected) : base(expected)
    {
    }

    public override string Description
        => Regex.Replace(base.Description, @"^\s*collection containing", "collection containing any of");

    /// <summary>
    /// Test whether any member in expected collection is available in actual collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actual">Actual collection</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool Matches(IEnumerable actual)
    {
        var convertedExpected = (IEnumerable<T>)Expected;
        var convertedActual = EnsureHasSameGenericType(actual, typeof(T));
        return convertedActual.Any(x => convertedExpected.Contains(x));
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> EnsureHasSameGenericType(IEnumerable actual, Type expectedType)
    {
        var sourceType = actual.GetType();
        var sourceGeneric = sourceType.IsArray
            ? sourceType.GetElementType()
            : sourceType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
        if (sourceGeneric == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("The actual collection must contain valid generic argument");
        if (!sourceGeneric.Equals(expectedType))
            throw new ArgumentException($"The actual is collection of {sourceGeneric.Name} but the expected is collection of {expectedType.Name}");
        return (IEnumerable<T>)actual;
    }
}

public static class ConstraintExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a new <see cref="CollectionContainsAnyConstraint{T}"/> checking for the
    /// presence of any object of the <see cref="expected"/> collection against actual collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <param name="expected">A collection where one of its member is available in actual collection</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static CollectionContainsAnyConstraint<T> ContainsAny<T>(this ConstraintExpression expression,
        params T[] expected)
    {
        var constraint = new CollectionContainsAnyConstraint<T>(expected);
        expression.Append(constraint);
        return constraint;
    }
}
```

and the usage will look like this

```
[TestFixture]
class GivenCustomCollectionContainsTest
{
    const string User8 = "user8";
    const string User9 = "user9";
    private readonly List<string> users = new List<string> { "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5" };

    [Test]
    public void WhenActualContainsOneOfExpectedAndPreceededByNotOperatorThenItShouldFail()
    {
        var actual = users.ToList();
        actual.Add(User8);

        var assert = Assert.Throws<AssertionException>(() => Assert.That(actual, Does.Not.ContainsAny(User8, User9)));
        Assert.That(assert.ResultState.Status, Is.EqualTo(TestStatus.Failed));
        Assert.That(assert.Message, Does.Contain("not collection containing any of").And.Contain($"\"{User8}\""));
    }

    [Test]
    public void WhenActualContainsAllOfExpectedAndPreceededByNotOperatorThenItShouldFail()
    {
        var actual = users.ToList();
        actual.Add(User8);
        actual.Add(User9);

        var assert = Assert.Throws<AssertionException>(() => Assert.That(actual, Does.Not.ContainsAny(User8, User9)));
        Assert.That(assert.ResultState.Status, Is.EqualTo(TestStatus.Failed));
        Assert.That(assert.Message, Does.Contain("not collection containing any of").And.Contain($"\"{User8}\", \"{User9}\""));
    }
}
```

Just note that this is intended for negative test only. Fortunately, I don't need a test that "any member of a collection is available in another collection" at the moment. Mostly, it tests for a collection is part of another collection, therefor, I can use `Is.SupersetOf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CollectionAssert.IsNotSubsetOf()`

```
CollectionAssert.IsNotSubsetOf(new[] {user8Name, user9Name }), users);
```

**Update:**

Well, you can always use basic looping.

```
Array.ForEach(new[] { user8, user9 }, u => Assert.That(users, Has.No.Member(u)));
```

This will check whether `users` contains any instances in the `new[] { user8, user9 }` array by looping it.

The error message will be something like this:

> Expected: not collection containing "user8"
>     But was:  < "user1", "user8", "user2", "user3" >

Comment: The scenario expects to fail because it contains user8

Comment: `boolean` testing always works although it doesn't suite in this condition, because whenever test fail, it generate non informative message. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @iroel The updated answer provide better error message, but it is still not a built-in function, although you can always use extension method. I just leave it here in-case it is sufficient enough for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the list of exclusions against the users

```
const string user8 = "user8";
const string user9 = "user9";
string[] users = { "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", user8 };

Assert.Multiple(() => {
    var exclude = new[] { user8, user9 }; 
    foreach(var user in exclude) {
        Assert.That(users, Has.No.Member(user));
    }
}
```

This test should fail because the list of users does contain `user8`

NUnit Docs - [CollectionContainsConstraint](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/CollectionContainsConstraint)

Comment: In this scenario, the test should fail, because the `users` contains `user8`.

Comment: as it should. you indicated `I want to test that the users does not contain either user8 or user9` which means test should fail if user8 is in the the list of user. Clarify what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's the test expectation. The goal is looking for built in syntax so the error message will have relevant message as well. This will work in most case. Is it possible to write custom constraint containing this code?